# Profiling/Debugging in OpenMP - Linux and free?

Tags: debugging, profiling, openmp

I am trying to find some good *free* OpenMP debuggers and profilers. 
What do you guys use that works on Linux RHEL 6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To some extent one can use `gdb` and `valgrind` to debug such applications, but these tools have very rudimentary support for OpenMP. Fortunately two big vendors recognise, that having their advanced development tools available for free for Linux is a good idea.

- [Oracle Solaris Studio](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/solaris/studio/features/index.html) for Linux is free and comes complete with an optimising compiler, debuger, a Netbeans-based IDE that integrates both, and a suite of performance tools like Performance Analyzer and Thread Analyzer.
- [Intel Software Development Tools](http://software.intel.com/en-us/linux-tool-suites/) for Linux can be obtained and used for [non-commercial software development](http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development) for free. Intel Parallel Studio XE includes the VTune Amplifier and Inspector applications and both are invaluable when debugging threaded code.